# Is there any way to co-locate two instances on a single physical core on a compute node?

Tags: openstack, nova

I'm gonna create a new flavor with `--vcpus` attribute set to `1` and set the `--property hw:cpu_policy` to `dedicated` so any instance launched with that flavor would be pinned on a fixed physical core on that host. I also assume if I make a host aggregate then another newly launched instance enter code herein that host aggregate & with the same flavor as first instance would be located beside the first one on the same physical core.

Now I wounded if there's any way that I could check if they'd actually been located on the same physical core or not. So far all the command I came into just display the host node on which instances has been placed but not the specific physical core.

If I'm lost on the topic please any idea how I could have co-located instances on a single physical core?

Answer (score 0):

It seems no one is interested in the topic, well there is this `virsh` command that one can run on the host an instance is placed on and get variety of informations. For my purpose `virsh dumpxml <instance id> | grep vcpupin` is helpful.